# Am I dividing the time of day correctly in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, time, ms-access-2010

I have a field that has a bunch of shifts where SH1 is from 6am-2pm, SH2 is from 2pm-10pm, and SH3 is from 10pm-6am. I need to only return the current shift, based on the current time.

**What I've tried:**

```
Switch(
    [Uf_Shift_Standard]=8,
        (Switch(
        (Time() >= #6 am# AND Time() < #2 pm#), "SH1",
        (Time() >= #2 pm# AND Time() < #10 pm#), "SH2",
        True, "SH3")
        ),

        [Uf_Shift_Standard]=10,
            (Switch(
            (Time() >= #5 am# AND Time() < #3 pm#), "SH1",
            True, "SH2")),

            [Uf_Shift_Standard]=12,
                (Switch(
                (Time() >= #3 am# AND Time() < #3 pm#), "SH1",
                True, "SH2")),

                1=1,
                    (Switch(
                    (Time() >= #6 am# AND Time() < #2 pm#), "SH1",
                    (Time() >= #2 pm# AND Time() < #10 pm#), "SH2",
                    True, "SH3"))
    )
```

**Note:** I've updated my code to account for the 3 different types of shift lengths we have - an 8, 10, and 12 hour shift. However, I'm not getting the error: `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'tableA.job="something" And tableB.suffix="12" And tableB.shift=Switch([Uf_Shift_Standard]=8,Switch...[the rest of the long expression continues here...]`

The `'tableA.job="something" And tableB.suffix="12"` part deals with 2 other columns before the shift column that have criteria of their own.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a one-liner:

```
Shift = "SH" & 1 + DatePart("h", DateAdd("h", -6, Time())) \ 8
```

In the GUI designer:

```
Shift: "SH" & 1+DatePart("h",DateAdd("h",-6,Time()))\8
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything.

Comment: Actually, it returns -1 when I use it as a field. Access converts this to Shift `"SH" & 1 + DatePart("h", DateAdd("h", -6, Time())) \ "8"` btw.

Comment: Don't know what you do. The code line cannot return anything else than SH1, SH2, or SH3.